# Checking Existing Sheet names in list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check whether an existing tab or worksheet is in a list of tab names, say in Column A. Column A is found in a tab called Import RPT.

If the name exists I want the code to end and create a MsgBox saying that a spreadsheet already exists in row i of column A, if not continue.

I've combined pieces from Stack Overflow:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Range

With Sheets("Import RPT")
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        Set r = sht.Cells.Range("C2:C" & Count)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("rngSheetInclusions"), sht.Name) > 0 Then
            strResult = strResult & "Duplicate Name: " & r & vbNewLine & "Rows: " & _
            Left(dict.Item(r), Len(dict.Item(r)) - 1) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            MsgBox strResul

    Next
```

Comment: What is your question and what is your issue? You didn't ask a question yet. Also you should tell where exactly you got stuck or errors. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and [ask]. Also your code cannot work because there is an `End If` missing right before `Next`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Does column A have a list of worksheet names in it? Also, are you using a dictionary object? I don't see it dimensioned anywhere. If so, how are you allocating it?

Comment: The Macro reads in files from a file directory in a separate column and adjacent to each of these, I want to input these into named tabs(column A). So I want a Macro to fail when trying to import a file in column B if there are duplicate named tabs in Column A.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Function SheetExists(s as string) As Boolean
     'Returns true if s is the name of a sheet in the current workbook
     On Error Goto NOPE
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s)
     SheetExists = True
     Exit function

 NOPE:
     SheetExists = False
 End function
```

Once you have this function, you can enter `=SheetExists(A1)` in cell B1 and it will show true or false. Then drag down the rest of b adjacent to your tab names

Comment: If you want to test for `Sheets` then `Dim ws As Object`. If you want to test for `Worksheets` then `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s)` and name function `WorksheetExists`. • Why? Because `Sheets` contains also `Charts` and not only `Worksheets`.